# HTTP request, with custom tcp socket

Tags: node.js, tcp, tunnel

I want to create HTTP request over a custom tcp socket.
How can i build a HTTP request, with headers & all, and send them over a custom tcp socket ?

No success with the standart http module.

```js
var request = http.request({
    //host: 'example.com',
    path: '/endpoint',
    //port: 80,
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': "blublu",
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
}, function (response) {

    var reply = '';
    response.on('data', function (chunk) {
        reply += chunk;
    });

    response.on('end', function () {
        return console.log(reply);
    });

});

   
request.toPlainRequest(); // send output over my custom socket
```

If i run the code above, it trys to connect to 127.0.0.1:80...
I just want the http headers & stuff you pass over the tcp socket to the server.

EDIT: i found a possible solution, there is a option "createConnection" which create the underlying tcp socket.

Comment: Looks like `createConnection` is the right choice. Have you tried it?

Comment: Yep, works great!